# Puppet Unscheduling all events on Stage [main]

Tags: puppet

I have an issue with Puppet and want to understand it better. When I run puppet agent -t on my client it runs and recognises an Exec command which is triggered from a refresh event.

The Exec doesn't execute at all and I have noticed that a little later in the /var/log/messages there is another input which says
Unscheduling all events on Stage [main]

What I need to know is, is it this Unscheduling that is stopping my Exec command from running?

Comment: In the first paragraph you say the `exec` resource is applied and executes, but then in the second paragraph you say it does not. Are these two different resources? We would need to see the non-applying resource and its notifier to assist further.

Comment: The diagnostic message you describe  reflects at least one resource-application failure having occurred earlier in the run.  That will have been logged too, and it's what you need to resolve first.

Comment: Looks like error in exec resource , fix that error, because that resource have some dependant resources, so only you are facing this Unscheduling event error